# Как получить доступ к элементам GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Как мне поменять свойства `TextView`, который находится НЕ в `activity_main.xml`, а является элементом `item.xml` в `GridView`.

**item.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rect"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

И метод `onCreate()` из **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

GridView gridView;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView)  findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    String [] data = {"a","3","d","f","s","p","X","1","2","3"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,R.layout.item, R.id.textViewItem,data);

    gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
```

`textView.setTextSize()` выдает ошибку, т.к. `textView` остается `null` (как я нагуглил, `findViewById()` не присваивает ссылку к переменной `textView`, т.к. не находит такой view в layout, для которой вызывался `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Как достучаться до элемента в `item.xml`?

Comment: а вы пробовали`textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);` только нужно указать индекс или на самом деле это лучше делать в адапторе

Comment: Оборачивание в `LinearLayout` в *item.xml* лишнее, вы можете присвоить тот же бэкграунд и самому `TextView`.  Атрибуты `layout_alignParentLeft`, `layout_alignParentStart`,  `layout_alignParentTop` в *activity_main.xml* лишние - первый элемент и так расположится в верхнем левом углу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, почему вы не указали размер текста прямо в `item.xml`, но вы можете переопределить `getView()` в `ArrayAdapter` и создать любой удобны вам layout. Например, так:

```
int itemTextSize  = 25;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item, R.id.textViewItem,data) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View root = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, itemTextSize);
            return root;
        }
    };

  ...
}
```

Если вам нужно менять размер текста динамически, то в данном случае можно изменить значение `itemTextSize` и затеме вызывать `notifyDataSetChanged()` у вашего адаптера.

Например, можно увеличить размер текста через 5 секунд:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            itemTextSize = 40;
            ((BaseAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например достучаться так:

```
int itemsCnt = arrayAdapter.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < itemsCnt; i++) {
  View v = arrayAdapter.getView(i, null, gridView);
  if (v != null && v instanceof LinearLayout) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) v).getViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
  }
}
```

//// ... sorry